# Pandas time series rolling mean: difference between window = '365D' and 365

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate rolling mean of time series data. However there seems to be discrepencies when I use window='365D' and window=365, why is this the case?

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 31)
aapl = pdr.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start, end)['Close']

mean_365D = aapl.rolling('365D').mean()
mean_365 = aapl.rolling(365).mean()

mean_365D.plot()
mean_365.plot()
```

[image: Blue=365D, Orange=365]

Blue is 365D and Orange is 365.

Comment: I can't verify that: df.rolling works as expected. As soon as you are able to formulate the problem comprehensibly and reproducible, you will probably be able to solve it yourself. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your reply. I resampled daily data to get montly data. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Not if done properly.

Comment: Hi Peter, I changed the wording of the question and provided the dataset. Can you please have a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aapl timeseries consists of business days only, which is ~252 days per year. A rolling windows average like `aapl.rolling('365D').mean()` will build the mean based on the period of 365 calendar days, which corresponds to those ~252 business days. In contrast the `aapl.rolling(365).mean()` averages over 365 observations, which is almost 1.5 years. Hence the difference.